# What do you call a chief clergyman in a church?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a chief clergyman in a church, a person who is in charge of a church?

Comment: That would depend on the denomination and in some cases the individual church. Also, do you mean "church" in the sense of an entire denomination, or "church" in the sense of an individual building, its staff and its congregation? Or something in between the two?

Comment: “rector”, at least in the churches I know.

Comment: *Rector* of a Roman Catholic church and *vicar* of a Church of England one? It's more complicated than I thought!

Comment: @rjpond the latter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the denomination, the local area and dialect

A "vicar" is probably the term you want to use, especially in England.

"Rector" is the administrative lead cleric for a parish church (one parish usually has one but may have several churches) Nowadays "rector" and "vicar" are essentially equal in rank in the Church of England, but in Catholic churches, rectors outrank vicars.

You could describe vicars and rectors as "parish priests" Catholics in the USA call the parish priest a "pastor".

In Protestant churches, leader of the church may be called a "minister" or "pastor", and not a priest.

Quaker churches have no clergy at all, the church is run by a committee of "friends".

So there is no simple answer, but "vicar" would probably work in many situations, especially in England.

Comment: Weird! Your answer only showed up after I posted my comment! How'd that happen?!

Comment: And the person in charge of a cathedral, at least in the UK, is the _dean_. They therefore outrank the bishop of the surrounding diocese within the cathedral

Comment: What about a person who is in charge of a Catholic church (a building)?

Comment: You probably want "Rector".  But I just checked our local catholic church and "Father Jack" is termed "Priest in Charge" and doesn't hold the office of rector.  His subordinate is termed "deacon".  It is simply the case that there isn't a simple answer to this. question.  Different churches, even in the some country, might use different words.